# How to implement Serialization in java

Tags: java

Hi i'm looking for any open source available to implement the best in class serialization.

I'm talking about , Is there any opensource(which is popular) which handles the serialization better .

Comment: Is that "**best-in-class** serialization", or "best in **class-serialization**"?

Comment: Please ask a more specific question.  Given the context you've given us, we can't beat Google.

Comment: Do you want to implement your own serializer, or are you asking about existing ones?

Comment: `public class Foo implements Serializable`

Comment: Hmm. Two close-votes, two up-votes and one down-vote.... I'll never understand you lot.

Comment: I'm going to throw this out there, but 'better' is not a good qualifier.  Better than what?  Are you trying to improve default Java Serialization?  If so, in what way(s) do you want it to be improved: data size, performance, other?  It's hard to provide a path to follow without a defined destination.

Comment: Perhaps he meant 'breakfast cereal' not 'best-in-class' serial?

Comment: @bmargulies: Exactly, You identified I want  'breakfast cereal',but it is already lunch time . I'm really hungry ! I got some good answers , thanks for those people ,  Looks you don't have any more :) , or probbaly you may not have understood like these people  Mark Peters, aioobe, Amir Raminfar, Tom Hawtin - tackline,

Comment: checkout fast-serialization/fst on github

Answer (score 4):

Serialization is built in to java.  For most classes you can simply implement `java.io.Serializable` and your classes "magically" becomes serializable.  Then you can use `java.io.ObjectOutputStream` & `java.io.ObjectInputStream` to read and write your objects.

If you require custom serialization, then add the following methods to your class to override the serialization behavior.  They have to match these signatures **exactly**:

```
private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
  //YOUR WRITE CODE HERE
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
  // YOUR READ CODE HERE
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Either have a look at the Java source code (Yes, it comes with the JDK, but is zippen in a file called src.zip), or look at [JBossSerialization](http://www.jboss.org/serialization), which is faster and reduces the size of the serialized objects. I have written my own some time ago, which is 6 times faster and produces 6 times less data, but it requires the exact class structure to be known to both sides, so it is just usable as a communication protocol and not for persistant storage.

Comment: Thanks, I'm almost looking for this kind answer

Comment: fast serialization (github) has same level of compatibility while being much faster than JBoss serialization

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)? As other commenters have, I'm having a hard time with your question as originally written.